# ошибка при обрашении на веб сервис, статус 404

Tags: java, java-ee, веб-служба, jersey, jax-rs

Банальный но непонятный пример веб сервиса.

Почему не находит ресурс и в чём может быть проблема ?

- При попытке задеплоить с Maven получаю ошибку. 
  В чём может быть проблема ?

  > > [FATAL] Non-parseable settings /home/maks/.m2/settings.xml: 
  > >     expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...since   these pairings are\n     |       used together.\n     |\n

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
     @Path("/Get")
     public class GetTest {

     @GET
     @Produces(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_XML)
     public void helloTest(){

    System.out.println("Get");
    }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="http://localhost:8080/CouponSystem/Get">

<label for="get">GetSome:</label>
<input id="get" name="get" type="text"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   

 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   

 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 

  id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <display-name>CouponSystem</display-name>

<servlet>

<servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

<init-param>
<param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
<param-value>coupon.register</param-value>
</init-param>

</servlet>

<servlet>

 <servlet-name>Get</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

 <init-param>
 <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
 <param-value>coupon.service.GetTest</param-value>
 </init-param>

 </servlet>


 <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Get</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Get</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/register/post</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 404 - не найдена страница, два варианта - либо по неверному урлу обращаетесь, либо не задеплоилось.

Comment: пр попытке задеплоить получаю ошибку.

Comment: Что в файле /home/maks/.m2/settings.xml проверьте что все теги открыты и закрыты как надо.

Comment: Надо было убрать прошедшие комменты.